# How can I integrate this Scrollable Tab library in Eclipse?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm banging my head with [this](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) **Scrollable Tab library**, but didn't get success.

The website itself have a little amount of details in it.
My Questions are:

1. **How can I integrate is in my application in Eclipse**?: I tried to add it as library, but not working.
2. I haven't **seen any layout** to draw this control.
3. Also when I tried to integrate it, with just copy-paste scr, res, & lib folders, I get **PageIndicator, CirclePageIndicator, LinePageIndicator cannot be resolver error**. I had added external jar support for Android supprt lib v4. but it was still not working.

If anybody had used this Scrollable Tab library, please help me with this.
And if you have another reference to scrollable tab plugin, please share with me.

I tried to mail to developer, but he didn't replied to my mail yet, that's why I have to come to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the scrollable Tab library. It is Page indicator library.
which you can use with View pager of Android Support Library and ActionBarSherlock.

To use it they give a example. You need to Import their project as a library. And then add library in you project.

Then try their example. I hope it will help you.:)

EDIT: HOW to:

1. Download project [from](http://viewpagerindicator.com/)
2. now import the library folder project in eclipse
3. now in your project right click > Android > Library > add (a pop open select "library") :)
4. Now try their [example](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) under headding Usage.

Comment: What u mean? Shud i Import this library in my app? Can you please please mention steps?

Comment: Thankx alot @Mohsin. You don;t know how much u helped me.. Thankx again.